# Apache 2 monitor http requests

Tags: apache

I have an Apache 2 server that hosts some plain binary files, that are reachable through an URL on one of the servers virtual hosts. 
Right now I can see my traffic in the access.log - but my question is.
Is it possible somehow to monitor requests to this virtual host and execute a shell script on each request. 
In retrospect this could have been done by a simple PHP script - but at this point I don't want to change the URLs for the files.